# Applying function over data.table and storing results in a list

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with the following format:

```
ColName  xvalue   yvalue

Column1  5       10
Column2  3        5
Column3  2        4
```

I have defined a function as follows:

```
opt <- function (x,y){
return(x+y)
}
```

I want to apply the function over each row of the data.table and store the resulting value in a list like below:

```
x
$column1
[1]15

$column2
[1]8

$column3
[1]6
```

Essentially I am applying a function that takes each row of the data.table as input parameters and stores the output as members of a list. Is there a data.table way of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: `lapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) opt(data[x,2],data[x,3]))`

Comment: The data.table way would be to not create this list. You are essentially splitting a data.table by rows and that should be avoided because it is inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map` to get output as list :

```
setNames(Map(opt, df$xvalue, df$yvalue), df$ColName)

#$Column1
#[1] 15

#$Column2
#[1] 8

#$Column3
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do,

```
split(rowSums(df[-1]), df$ColName)

#$Column1
#[1] 15

#$Column2
#[1] 8

#$Column3
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to apply the `opt` and then use `as.list`

```
with(df1, as.list(setNames(opt(xvalue, yvalue), ColName)))
#$Column1
#[1] 15

#$Column2
#[1] 8

#$Column3
#[1] 6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColName = c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3"), 
    xvalue = c(5L, 3L, 2L), yvalue = c(10L, 5L, 4L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```